# PHP. Проблема со сторонним FTP сервером. Подключаюсь, читаю файл, записывать обратно отредактированный файл отказывается.(fputs)

Tags: php, linux, ftp, скрипт

Есть скрипт php. Он подключается к стороннему FTP серверу, считывает файл в локальную переменную, дописывает в переменную нужные, затем полностью заменяет содержимое файла на переменную на сервере( fputs($ftpfile,$text) ). Тестил скрипт у себя через xampp php 5.6.3 все работает, когда залил на хостинг, не работает. Версия php на хостинге 5.4 - в чем может быть проблема? Опытным путем выяснил что не срабатывает именно fputs (пробовал fwrite, тоже безрезультатно). Почитал про права доступа. Поставил 777. Все равно не пашет. В чем может быть проблема?

```
if($lines = file("$ftp_configs_path/users.ini")) //&&
{
    $last = count($lines);
    $lines[$last] = $new_comm;
    $lines[$last+1] = $new_user;
    $inftp = "";
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $inftp .= $line;
    }
    $stream_options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
    $stream_context = stream_context_create($stream_options);
if ($fh = fopen("$ftp_configs_path/users.ini", 'w', 0, $stream_context))
    {
      fputs($fh, $inftp);
      fclose($fh); 
    }
}
```

Comment: что не работает?

Comment: От какого пользователя подключаетесь к ftp? попробуйте зайти через мэнэджер ftp, к примеру filezilla и создать\отредактировать фаил, и смотрите на ошибку.

Comment: Через FileZilla все работает: редактирует, сохраняет (ошибок нет). Проблема в том, что я у себя на локальном компьютере выполнял этот скрипт и он работал(то есть: он подключался к FTP, читал файл, сохранял содержимое себе, редактировал содержимое, полностью затирал файл и записывал в него данные вновь). Что на сайте, что у себя - подключение идет от одинакового пользователя FTP. В чем может быть проблема?